# Cleaning unstructured data in Word with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am cleaning a Word document that is in German. The converted text has a TabStop at the end of every line (I think - see screenshot) that ends far before the margin. I am trying to either delete the TabStops in VBA or replace it with a normal spacebar character. I believe that the "TabStops" is an object that somehow needs to be defined?
[image]

[image]

Any suggestions what VBA code would clean this string efficiently?
Thank you! - Emily

Comment: those are paragraph markers, not tab stops. that may help you find the correct code to use remove them

Comment: Iterate your paragraphs and if the paragraph doesn't have a paragraph indent set then delete the character before the paragraph.  I'd do this in reverse, i.e. For pCount = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count to 2 Step -1.

Comment: See https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/29880-cleaning-text-pasted-websites-mails-pdfs-etc.html

Comment: These comments were super helpful! I have been able to automate the cleaning process of this 400-page document!! Thank y'all so much! @macropod